# Как подключиться через OAuth к Одноклассникам?

Tags: java, oauth, одноклассники

```
https://api.ok.ru/oauth/token.do?code={code}&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&grant_type={grant_type}
```

Вот ссылка для авторизации в одноклассниках. Как мне узнать `client_id` и `client_secret`? Обязательно ли создавать свое приложение на данном сайте для этого?

---

**UPD**

Создал приложение в одноклассниках, получил `application_id`, `application_secret` и публичный ключ приложения на почту.

```
https://connect.ok.ru/oauth/authorize?client_id=мой_ключ_приложения&scope=VALUABLE_ACCESS;PHOTO_CONTENT&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://www.ok.ru/`
```

После редиректа в браузере на секунду появляется `access_token`, а потом переходит на `redirect_url`. Как мне получить этот `access_token`?

Answer (score 3):

Нужно создать приложение. В его параметрах/свойствах (не знаю, как этот пункт называется в ОК) обычно и указывают `client_id` и `client_secret`.

В параметрах приложения нужно будет указать адрес для редиректа - это URL на который будет перенаправлен браузер пользователя после попытки авторизации, при чем не важно, успешной или нет.

Так же, при редиректе в url будет добавлен access_token, необходимый для работы с API.

Comment: там меня просят указать страницу редиректа, картинку и прочую лабуду. Мне лишь надо авторизоваться и использовать функции работы с фотографиями. Без приложения никак не получится такое сделать?

Comment: @Herrgott, без приложения авторизоваться? :)

Comment: @Herrgott, я дополнил ответ.